# Flutter Web main.dart.js.map issue

Tags: google-chrome, flutter

I have deployed one flutter web app. when it is loaded in console I can see the error as follows.

is this file require for functional website?

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: See an interesting comment on that topic in GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72150#issuecomment-743710110